# C# Abstract Class Instanitiation

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I found out my service classes always have a pattern, so that i want to have an abstract class. but I would like to implement some base methods inside the abstract class, and each child class inherits this abstract class has its own repo class, how to implement a new generic type of repo inside this abstract class ? and for example, can I create a constructor inside abstract class to initialize this EList with data so that I will write less code.

the abstract class below:

```
public abstract class ServiceBase<TEntity,TModel> : IService<TModel>
{
    protected internal abstract List<TEntity> EList { get; }

    public long Create(TModel entity)
    {

    }

    public long Delete(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public TModel Read(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public long Update(TModel entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Let's say all methods inside the abstract class will need to use this generic Repo Class, and this Repo Class will be defined in each child class, should I put TRepo at here public abstract class ServiceBase, will TRepo be declared a new instance at child class or is there any better implementation ?

---

one of the child class

```
public class ItemModifierService : ServiceBase<ItemModifierEntity, ItemModifierModel>
{
    private ItemModifierRepository IMRepo = new ItemModifierRepository();

    private List<ItemModifierEntity> IMEList = new List<ItemModifierEntity>();

    public ItemModifierService()
    {
        IMEList = IMRepo.Read(false);
    }


    public ItemModifierModel Read()
    {

    }

    public ItemModifierModel Read(int id)
    {

    }

    public long Create(ItemModifierModel entity)
    {

    }

    public long Update(ItemModifierModel entity)
    {

    }

    public long Delete(int id)
    {

    }

    public bool Exist(int id)
    {
        return IMEList.Any(x => x.id == id);
    }
}
```

How can I convert this constructor

```
public ItemModifierService()
{
    IMEList = IMRepo.Read(false);
}
```

into generic one and implement it inside abstract class so that I do not have to write more code in each child class or expand this constructor with more customized lines of code in child class ?

Thank you all in advanced.

have a lovely day.

Comment: Do you really want one list in your base class and one in your derived class as well? As for how you write a constructor in an abstract class: exactly the same way that you do in a concrete class...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Thanks for your comment, Yes, because generally all service class has its own list of object entity from database by using the repo class. the list can be generic type as well as the repo, I will only define it in child class, in that way I believe will be much more efficient in coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way without understanding the domain of your problem would be create an instance in deriving class and pass it down to a generic attribute in base class like so:

```
public interface IRepo<Item> {
    public List<Item> Read(bool arg);
}

public abstract class ServiceBase<TEntity,TModel, TRepo> : IService<TModel> where TRepo : IRepo<TEntity>
{
    protected internal abstract List<TEntity> EList { get; private set; }
    protected internal TRepo repo { get; private set; };

    public ServiceBase(TRepo instance)
    {
        this.repo = instance;
        this.EList = this.repo.Read(false);
    }
}

public class ItemModifierService : ServiceBase<ItemModifierEntity, ItemModifierModel, ItemModifierRepository> {
    public ItemModifierService() : base(new ItemModifierRepository()) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, may I know why I have to pass TRepo into constructor inside abstract class ? will I be able to use this TRepo instance for all other methods within child class ?

Comment: You pass it down because the abstract class doesn't know how to initialize the Repository object, for example your Item repo might need some arguments inside it's constructor like so: `new ItemModifierRepository(someArgument)`. As for the second part - yes, `protected` means that you will be able to access this attribute in all child classes. I've edited the code to make `repo` have a `private set` so only the abstract class can set it, but all child classes can use it